# How does set -- something work?

Tags: linux, shell, set

I've written a quite extensive shell script and some of the functionality I obtained by doing research here on stackoverflow.  One of the things I implemented, but didn't fully understand, is the use of `set -- something`.

I've read the `help set` command but I'm still having trouble understanding how it's implementation works in the following scenario:

```
#!/bin/sh

params="$(getopt abc:d: $*)"
```

if I then do

`set -- $params`

What exactly is `set` doing there?

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted my question without leaving any feedback!  That really helps me to see how I could have made the question more clear.

Comment: The downvote is not about making it clear.  It's about not doing fundamental basic research, such as reading the man page which would have answered your question immediately.  The purpose of SO is to provide answers that cannot be easily found elsewhere.  Questions with trivially findable answers do not contribute to the overall usefulness of SO.

Comment: Why tag this `linux`? There's nothing Linux-specific about POSIX sh behavior.

Comment: I upvoted the question as also @JimGarrison's answer. I am a little bit troubled by the downvote. Jim has a point but I seen far worse on SO that have not been downvoted.

Comment: @1_CR You and nkon both have a point. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: @nkon: How is anyone supposed to know you *did* do research? Your question would be better received if you had written something like "I read the documentation for ... but I don't understand what it means by ...." (I've neither upvoted nor downvoted.)

Comment: @KeithThompson you are right.  I'll edit my thread with that information.  Thanks for the feedback.  I guess what looks extremely simple to some doesn't seem that way to others.  Now that I understand my issue, I can see the simplicity and understand the resulting reactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `set -- "$(getopt abc:d: $*)"` does, in short, is create bugs. That's not specific to `set`, though it is necessarily incidental to use of `getopt`; however, it's also generic to the use of `$*`.

Consider the following:

```
./yourscript -f"./filename with spaces"
```

`$*` squashes all arguments together into a string -- after which, because it's unquoted, those arguments are split apart again according to the contents of `IFS`: `./filename with spaces` into three arguments: `./filename`, `with`, and `spaces`. Don't do that. Instead, follow the practices at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 (yes, it's called BashFAQ, but it covers POSIX-compliant mechanisms as well as bash-specific ones).

That said, to discuss what it's INTENDED to do, the following is a working exemplar:

```
$ getopt abc:d: -a -c foo bar baz
 -a -c foo -- bar baz
```

...and the following is an example of why `getopt` is broken even when not using `$*` (see how the single argument `foo bar` is split apart into two separate pieces, `foo` and `bar`):

```
$ getopt abc:d: -a -c "foo bar" baz
 -a -c foo bar -- baz
```

...and the following is an example of why `set --` shouldn't ever be used in conjunction with string-splitting, which is how an unquoted expansion (such as `$params`) is split into multiple arguments:

```
$ params='-f "foo bar"'
$ set -- $params
$ printf '<%s> ' "$@"; echo
<-a> <"foo> <bar">
```

Instead, the correct way to manage lists of items to be put into the argument list is using arrays -- a bash extension, as POSIX sh simply *does not* allow any correct way to do this:

```
$ params=( -f "foo bar" )
$ set -- "${params[@]}"
$ printf '<%s> ' "$@"; echo
<-a> <foo bar>
```

In any of these cases, the argument vector (`$@`) is changed with the new contents by `set --`, to put positional arguments only after all the optional arguments, separated by `--`. However, it's changed INCORRECTLY: Multi-word arguments are string-split and recombined wrongly. Again, see the linked FAQ for the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is the type of explanation I was looking for, but couldn't find.  This is very clear now!

Comment: One more thing... (just to make sure I completely understand), `params=$(getopt abc:d: $*)` just takes my command-line params and splits them up.  `set -- $params` just takes that information and sets them to positional parameters because of the arg, `--` to the set command?

Comment: Exactly right; `params=$(getopt abc:d: $*)` reorganizes your arguments to separate positional arguments from options (and totally breaks arguments with whitespace in the process), and `set -- $params` changes `$@` according to the new values emitted by `getopt` (after another round of string-splitting and glob expansion, both of which are expansion stages best avoided).

Comment: @nkon I've updated it a bit more to provide examples of how `set --` works, both when used correctly and otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly covered in the [bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin).

> --
>
> If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset. Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the arguments, even if some of them begin with a ‘-’.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have clarified that I'm not using bash.

Comment: Since bash is the de facto standard shell, you must clarify.  Even so, since bash has assimilated the "best" (for some definition of "best" :-) parts of other shells, this is still likely the correct answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison I thought not tagging `bash` would suffice.

Comment: Doesn't matter, because it's the same for every POSIX-standard shell. Why are we arguing about this?